# New York Times API and NYT python library

Tags: python

I am trying to retrieve the parameter `web_url` on Python via the `newyorktimes` library. However, the query result on python is way smaller than the result from the NYT API.

This is my code:

```
from nytimesarticle import articleAPI

api = articleAPI("*Your Key*")
articles = api.search( q = 'terrorist attack')

print(articles['response'],['docs'],['web_url'])
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As you saw in the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), please be explict and include details on what you are trying to do. What result are you getting vs. what did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing pagination, try this:

```
articles = api.search( q = 'terrorist attack', page=1)
```

now you can keep incrementing `page` and get more articles. Its politely called RTFM [nytimesarticle](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nytimesarticle/0.1.0).

Answer (score 0):

Try 
    `@GET("{duration}.json")
    Call<MostPopularData> getMostPopularArticles(@Path("duration") int duration, @Query("api-key") String apiKey, @Query("offset") int offset);`

Offset must be positive and multiple of 20.